# NatTable 1.6->2.0 upgrade causes "Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder""

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, slf4j, nattable

I have an Eclipse RCP application which uses the NatTable component.

The application uses Log4J 2.19, libraries on the classpath, configured correctly etc and logging works fine to both console and file.

When I try to upgrade from NatTable 1.6 to 2.0, at runtime logging fails to work with the following error printed to the console:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

I'm aware ordinarily this would be caused by the libraries not being on the classpath but I don't think this is the problem here - my only guess is that the new version of NatTable dependency is including something else on the classpath that's messing up the dependency resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Well, with 2.0 NatTable switched to use SLF4J API instead of a concrete logging implementation. You need to add the Log4j2 SLF4J binding to the application to get rid of the warning.

Comment: I have `slf4j-api-1.7.32` and `log4j-slf4j-impl-2.19.0` on the classpath already, is thit eh Log4j SLF4J binding your talking about?

Comment: Should be yes. Maybe the impl bundle is not started

Comment: are you able to give an example of how the bundle should be started?

Comment: in the product configuration you probably need to set the bundle start to automatic for the slf4j binding bundles.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean by "set the bundle start to automatic". They are on the classpath and declared in the manifest and are accessible. I don't know where/what bundle start is.

Comment: Well, do you have a product configuration our how do you configure your application